# Disabling element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so I want to click an item, then have that item become unclickable, and not execute the jQuery attached to it. I am currently using this

```
$(clicked_id).prop('disabled', true);
```

However that is not working.

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:

This is the HTML:

```
<img src="imgs/card.jpg" id="card0" name="card0"  onclick="getCard(this.id); ">
```

Comment: how is it not working? Do you get an error? We need more code than what you've posted to help.

Comment: What is the element? You can't just add the `disabled` property to any arbitrary element and expect it to work. You need to code within the defined behavior of the element.

Comment: And is your `clicked_id` selector a proper id beginning with `#`?

Comment: what is the element type?

Comment: i've updated it with the HTML :)

Comment: your jQuery selector doesn't match your ID

Comment: @MattBusche: The selector is a variable.

Comment: @thesystem where does he set clicked_id = card0 ?

Comment: @MattBusche: He doeasn't show it explicitly, but it's still a variable. Very likely that the `this.id` passed to `getCard()` is received as a `clicked_id` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disabled` is only for disabling input elements (and it doesn't change the clickability of the object -- just that the default animation isn't executed).

To make it so that the click event is removed from an object, use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
 $(clicked_id).off('click')
```

But this only works if the onclick was added via jquery

Instead, you may do this:

```
$(clicked_id)[0].onclick=false
```

Comment: @SamStone: Could you give us a jsfiddle of your code? Exactly what do you mean by "this doesn't work"? What happens? Is there an error?

Comment: @SamStone: Never mind, I figured out the issue. See alternative method.

Comment: You're welcome! You can mark an answer accepted by clicking the checkmark (you should be able to do this in another 3 minutes). Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Since your handler is assigned as an attribute, you can just nullify the property for that event handler.

```
document.getElementById(clicked_id).onclick = null;
```

just make sure you don't have a leading `#` on the ID.

---

Or us jQuery like this:

```
$(clicked_id).prop("onclick", null);
```

---

Or you can pass the element itself instead of passing the ID.

```
<img src="imgs/card.jpg" id="card0" name="card0"  onclick="getCard(this); ">
```

And then change your function so that it receives the element instead of the ID of the element. Once you do that, you can access the element directly.

```
elem.onclick = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution:

```
function getCard(objId){ 
  if( !($('#'+objId).attr('used') == '1') )
  {
    alert('Click is working for '+objId);
    // do something
    $('#'+objId).attr('used', '1');
  } 
}
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/HqHut/